# Ruby use array as class arguments

Tags: ruby, class, arguments

I am making a class with a ton of arguments. I will have other classes with similar arguments.

I don't want to type all the arguments multiple times. I'm looking to do something like this:

```
argList = [arg1, arg2, arg3, ... arg100]

class myClass1
  def initialize(*argList)
    # ...
  end
end

class myClass2
  def initialize(*argList, extraArg1, ...)
    # ...
  end
end
```

But this doesn't work because the elements of `argList` are undefined variables.

So, is there a way to use an array as class arguments?

Comment: I might be wrong but a `initialize` method that requires dozens of arguments sounds like a code smell to me. I question at least if such a class still follows the single-responsibility principle and if you could and should separate concerns better. And that there are two classes that accept almost the same huge list of arguments makes this impression even worse. This definitely sounds like a [xy problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/284887) to me.

Comment: Good point, I think I can probably use the array itself as the arg, not each item. Just new to classes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of argList will not be undefined at run time.  If you comment out that line the following code runs fine.

```rb
# argList = [arg1, arg2, arg3, ... arg100]

class MyClass1
  def initialize(*argList)
    p *argList
    arg1, arg2, arg3 = *argList
    puts "arg1 = #{arg1}"
    # ...
  end
end

class MyClass2
  def initialize(*argList, extraArg1)
    p *argList
    puts "extraArg1 = #{extraArg1}"
    # ...
  end
end

my1 = MyClass1.new(1,2,3)
my3 = MyClass2.new(4,5,6,7)
```

@spickermann's comments still hold.
It would be strange for any method to require 100 **named** arguments.
What are the "arguments" you are passing in,  is it just an array of things you will process?  In that case just pass in an array not a splat-array.
Are they parameters representing some complex object?  In which case maybe you should consider creating the object, potentially a composed object, and passing that in.  Maybe you want to consider passing in a Hash object?

Comment: Thank you! Yeah I'll try just the array itself.